# Matplotlib: align bar plots with imgshow once on x axis and once on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a plot showing the sum of pixel intensities along the x and y axis.

Currently I have the following code:

```py
def example():
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
    
    ## <not under my control>
    
    np.random.seed(1455)
    
    width = 5
    height = 8
    
    sample = np.random.rand(height,width)
    
    x_hist = np.sum(sample, axis=0)
    y_hist = np.sum(sample, axis=1)
    
    ## </not under my control>
    
    fig = plt.figure()
    gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2)
    ax_joint  = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
    ax_marg_x = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0],sharex=ax_joint)
    ax_marg_y = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1],sharey=ax_joint)
    
    ax_joint.imshow(sample, cmap="Reds") 
    
    ax_marg_x.bar(range(width),x_hist)
    ax_marg_y.barh(range(height),y_hist)
    
    plt.show()
```

Which yields the following:

[image: example]

However the x axis of the upper bar plot and image have the same limits but aren't scaled or aligned
Also there is a large gap between the image and the right bar plot.

My desired result would be something along the lines of:

[image: desired result]

Comment: Use `aspect="auto"` in `imshow`?

Comment: That simply stretches the image, I'd rather keep the image so that each pixel is  a square

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, correct the aspect ratio to automatic and set the size of the figure to portrait. In addition, make the spacing between each narrower.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

np.random.seed(1455)

width = 5
height = 8

sample = np.random.rand(height,width)

x_hist = np.sum(sample, axis=0)
y_hist = np.sum(sample, axis=1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,8))
gs = fig.add_gridspec(2, 2, hspace=0.1, wspace=0.1)
ax_joint  = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax_marg_x = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0],sharex=ax_joint)
ax_marg_y = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 1],sharey=ax_joint)

ax_joint.imshow(sample, cmap="Reds", aspect='auto') 

ax_marg_x.bar(range(width),x_hist)
ax_marg_y.barh(range(height),y_hist)

plt.show()
```

[image]